# Generating PHPass for Wordpress Passwords

Tags: security, wordpress, authentication, md5, phpass

I am working on an application wnere I need to check for authenticity of user according to his wordpress userid/password. Trouble is, I don't know how to check whether a password is correct or not.

I read at [Wordpress MD5 Password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750395/wordpress-md5-password) that after wordpress 2.5 phpass http://www.openwall.com/phpass/ was being used for wordpress passwords instead of MD5.

Question is, If I have

1. Username Password in plain text
2. wordpress **Authentication Unique Keys and Salts** from **wp-config.php**
3. Database access

then How can:
1. I check whether user-name/password combination is correct.

2. Change password for user
3. Implement forgot password implementation

Wordpress version 3.0.4, Networked blogs being used with around 20 sites.

I know I should be doing it with native wordpress functions, but in this case it is not an option due to nature of the Wordpress settings.

I've spent over a week on this and still clueless! help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they implemented phpass without trying to 'improve' the library, you should be able to just use the phpass library to authenticate the users.

http://www.openwall.com/phpass/

Comment: although i had mentioned the link in my question itself, still selected your answer

Comment: -blinks- how could I not have seen that 8)